# MySQL WITH clause is acting wierd

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

WITH clause in SQL is not working. It works fine in my virtual machine but it is not working in my pythonanywhere server. I'm not sure what is making this error. Maybe because of the version difference?

I tried copying the exact same scenario in my virtual machine and it worked.

```
create table test_table (id int) engine=innodb;
WITH T1 as (select * from test_table) select * from T1;
```

It says to check the manual for MySQL server for the correct syntax.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? CTE was added in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: and in mariadb 10.2.1

Comment: as @Barmar said- PythonAnywhere MySQL dbs are < v8.0

Comment: I checked the SQL version in PythonAnywhere by doing "Select @@version" and it is 5.something. So I know what the problem is, now. Thank you so much, everyone.

Comment: Can someone please close this question?